# OpenGL multiple matrix transormations

Tags: delphi, opengl, matrix

I have simple vertex shader for models

```
#version 330

layout(location = 0) in vec3 VertexPosition;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 VertexNormal;
layout(location = 2) in vec2 VertexUV;

out VS_GS_VERTEX
{
    vec3 vs_worldpos;
    vec3 vs_normal;
    vec2 VertexUV;
} vertex_out;

uniform mat4 modelMatrix;
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 lookAtMatrix;

void main(void)
{
    mat4 MVP = projectionMatrix * lookAtMatrix * modelMatrix;

    gl_Position = MVP * vec4(VertexPosition, 1.0);
    gl_Normal = mat3(modelMatrix) * VertexNormal;

    vertex_out.vs_worldpos = gl_Position.xyz;
    vertex_out.vs_normal = gl_Normal;
    vertex_out.VertexUV = VertexUV;
}
```

and I pass there modelMatrix

```
  modelMat := MatrixMultiply(transMat, baseMat);
  modelMat := MatrixMultiply(modelMat, scaleMat);
  modelMat := MatrixMultiply(modelMat, rotMat);
  glUniformMatrix4fv(modelMatrix_loc, 1, false, @modelMat);
```

where transMat for positioning, scaleMat to enlarge whole picture and rotMat to rotate whole terrain.
[image: without scale]
Everything fine while baseMat is coordinates of model on terrain

```
baseMat := CreateTranslationMatrix(AffineVectorMake(pos.x, pos.y, pos.z));
```

but when I trying also to enlarge model by own model's scale (model have zero based coordinates, for example roots of tree at (0, 0, 0))

```
  scMat := CreateScaleMatrix(AffineVectorMake(scale, scale, scale));
  trMat := CreateTranslationMatrix(AffineVectorMake(pos.x, pos.y, pos.z));

  baseMat := MatrixMultiply(scMat, trMat);
```

[image: with model's scale]

models not just enlarged, they also changing coordinates and not placed on terrain anymore.
Is it possible to make one model matrix with model's scaling, rotation, translation, yet another translation, scaling and rotation? Or I should do something else? Matrix math from `GLScene` and seems works fine.

**Edit**: I can't use `proper order` with matrices by scaling first because I have this

[image: scaling image]
[image: scaling more]
The structure of terrain is tiles of 64x64 chunks, each have base coordinates. So to put it together I need first to translate each chunk to proper position and only then scale to enlarge image and rotate with mouse.
Each model also have absolute position assigned to terrain. I should scale and rotate model (own model's modifiers) and put it to proper position on terrain. `transMat` (to put tiles and models at the center of screen), `scaleMat` and `rotMat` shared for both terrain and models. But local `scMat` and `trMat` are for enlarge model and put it to right place.

If I leave terrain working as is with `rotMat * scaleMat * transMat` but using models as `rotMat * transMat * trMat * scaleMat * scMat` I have this
[image: models]
a bit closer
[image: 1 meter closer]

**Edit2**: changed vertex shader to

```
uniform mat4 modelMatrix;
uniform mat4 MVP;

void main(void)
{
    vec4 modelPos = modelMatrix * vec4(VertexPosition, 1.0);
    gl_Position = MVP * modelPos;
    gl_Normal = mat3(modelMatrix) * VertexNormal;

    vertex_out.vs_worldpos = gl_Position.xyz;
    vertex_out.vs_normal = gl_Normal;
    vertex_out.VertexUV = VertexUV;
}
```

and passed

```
modelMatrix = modelRotMat * modelScaleMat;
mvpMatrix = projMat * lookAtMat * rotMat * scaleMat * modelTransMat * transNat;
```

now it works as expected, thanks for help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to apply the scaling before the translation. The right order in which to apply matrices is

```
FinalMatrix = TranslationMatrix * RotationMatrix * ScaleMatrix;
```

(you may switch rotation and translation in specific cases, depending on what you want to rotate, but generally will be like this)
So, if you want to combine more of them, you'll have to do it this way;

```
FinalMatrix = TranslationMatrix1 *TranslationMatrix2* RotationMatrix1 * RotationMatrix2 * ScaleMatrix1*ScaleMatrix2;
```

**EDIT**

So, you have models with a base position rotation and scale on your terrain. And you want to add other transforms to them from time to time. You'll need a lot of matrices.
From the base coordinates on the terrain of you models, calculate `TranslationMatrix2`.
Your `CreateTranslationMatrix(AffineVectorMake(pos.x, pos.y, pos.z))` should be fine.
The basic scale and rotation of your model on the terrain should also be in `RotationMatrix2` and `ScaleMatrix2`. These three matrix hold the base scale position and orientation of each of your models on the terrain. Your final model matrix will be

```
ModelMatrix =  TranslationMatrix2 *RotationMatrix2 * ScaleMatrix2;
```

When you want to scale them or move them from that position, you can combine new transformations with those, with the formula. Let's say you want to apply a second scale, and new rotation and a new translation, whose matrices are `ScaleMatrix1`,`RotationMatrix1`, and `TranslationMatrix1`. Your final model matrix will be:

```
ModelMatrix =  TranslationMatrix1 *TranslationMatrix2*RotationMatrix1 * RotationMatrix2 * ScaleMatrix1*ScaleMatrix2;
```

**EDIT2**

If you want to keep that structure of your terrain, I think you have to scale the position of the models with the scale matrix used for the terrain. Then, from that position, compute the translation matrix of your model. Use the shared rotation matrix, and the model's own scale, like this

```
pos = scaleMat * pos;
trMat = CreateTranslationMatrix(AffineVectorMake(pos.x, pos.y, pos.z));
ModelMatrix = SharedRotation* scMat * trMat ;
```

Comment: Result looks weird: models like points and growing to fast on enlarging (assigned to mouse wheel). Probably because original terrain logic is: translate -> scale -> rotate. When I making terrain matrix math also like scale -> translate -> rotate at some point I can catch picture of trees at right size and positions. But map chunks split and scaling separately.  Making models like terrain `all translate together` -> `all scale` -> `all rotate` works!

Comment: Almost :( Lot of trees flying still. And I can't change logic to scale -> translate -> rotate because else my terrain not fit to models or split apart.

Comment: @user2091150 scale -> translate -> rotate the right way to apply any transform. It is a math thing, not a choice dependent on the algorithm you use. I'll edit my answer with more details.

Comment: The problem with `right order` is my terrain: I'll edit at the bottom with pictures to show issues I have when scaling first in several minutes.

Comment: Changed after `Edit` to explain issues with `rotMat * transMat * scaleMat`

Comment: @user2091150 I see, with the way your terrain is structured this is more complicated. I don't have time right now, but i have a question: what is transMat?

Comment: Doesn't the right order depend on what the rotation is about. Is it about the original origin, or the translated origin?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Of course. But the way 3D modelling programs works, it is always scale, rotation, translation. By the way the issue here is not about rotation vs translation, but about translation vs scale, for which the right order is scale, translation. The problem is that the terrain is structured in a way that needs translation, and then scale, which is an order you just can't use for the models.

Comment: transMat is   x := baseTileX * TILE_SIZE + TILES_TO_SHOW * TILE_SIZE / 2;
  y := baseTileY * TILE_SIZE + TILES_TO_SHOW * TILE_SIZE / 2;
  transMat := CreateTranslationMatrix(AffineVectorMake(-x, 0, -y));
so basically it is like move 4 tiles from coordinates like (30000, -17000, 0), swapped y an z, to center. Static for whole render pass. All I need from model (like bridge) is to scale it, properly rotate and put to terrain. Maybe it is possible in 2 passes for models?